# What does "with a jolt" mean? — (I sprang out of bed with a jolt. The car stopped with a jolt. Henry sat up with a jolt. The door closed with a jolt.)

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/jolt):

> jolt — a sudden, rough movement:
> **(1)** *I sprang out of bed with a jolt*.
> **(2)** *The car stopped with a jolt*.

---

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/jolt):

> jolt — a sudden shock:
> **(3)** *Henry sat up with a jolt*.

---

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jolt):

> jolt — a sudden jarring impact:
> **(4)** *The door closed with a jolt*.

---

The definitions of "*jolt*" don't help me fully understand the meaning of "*with a jolt*".
Could you tell me please what "*with a jolt*" means in each of these sentences?

Comment: if a bus stops, the driver could make it happen gently and smoothly, or they could just jam on the brakes very suddenly, so that the bus stops - bang! - and everybody is shifted on their seats.  Babies cry. Shopping bags spill. That's a jolt. If a bad man punched you in the head it would jolt your brains. What don't you understand about 'sudden and rough'?

Comment: And (1) and (3) refer to a person making a sudden, sharp movement.

Comment: I truly do not understand what you don't understand. Those definitions are pretty clear. It's a **metaphor for like an electrical shock**.

Comment: "The door closed with a jolt" doesn't strike me as idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary definitions are clear and written in normal English.  Perhaps you would find a more scientific description more helpful.  A jolt is normally associated with a rapidly changing acceleration, that is a large value of d³***x***/d*t*³, (and higher derivatives.)

When you receive a jolt, you are unable to compensate by bracing, and so  will tend to find yourself dislodged or unsettled.  Hence it is "sudden", "rough" and "jarring".

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a simple translation to russian. This may be a lexical gap in Russian.  Google suggests "Noun​: толчок удар потрясение тряска" but these are "push, hit, shock, shake", and "jolt" doesn't match exactly with any of them.

Comment: jolts are also associated with electrical shocks...